# When did Elizabeth Warren first refer to her Native American ancestry?

Tags: united-states, senate

I am assuming that Trump calls Elizabeth warren Pocahontas because at some point in the past she made reference to her Native American ancestry. Is this assumption correct?

If so, when/how did she reference her Native American ancestry? Was it on multiple occasions?

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/34462/why-is-elizabeth-warrens-native-american-ancestry-a-political-issue

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The earliest reference I know of is 1986, [when she was first listed as a minority professor](https://www.bostonglobe.com/metro/2012/05/02/elizabeth-warren-said-she-called-herself-minority-professor-find-other-people-like/QwbGsi49koIvsKcd83lr4M/story.html)

> [S]he acknowledged that for years before she joined the faculty at Harvard, she had been classifying herself as a minority professor in a directory of the Association of American Law Schools. That directory included Warren on a list of minority professors from 1986 through 1995.

Answer (score 10):

> I am assuming that Trump calls Elizabeth warren Pocahontas because at some point in the past she made reference to her Native American ancestry.

She did. From [the Boston Globe](http://archive.boston.com/news/local/massachusetts/articles/2012/05/31/elizabeth_warren_acknowledges_telling_harvard_penn_of_native_american_status/):

> Democratic Senate candidate Elizabeth Warren acknowledged for the first time late Wednesday night that she told Harvard University and the University of Pennsylvania that she was Native American, but she continued to insist that race played no role in her recruitment.
>
> “At some point after I was hired by them, I . . . provided that information to the University of Pennsylvania and Harvard,’’ she said in a statement issued by her campaign. “My Native American heritage is part of who I am, I’m proud of it and I have been open about it.’’

Comment: Trump did not originate this. She was first called Pocahontas, then Fauxcahontas way back in 2012 in her first fun for the US Senate.

Comment: @Mayo what do you mean by originate? I never claimed he was the one to first call her this. I merely provide a source on the name-calling.

Comment: Ah. K. Read quickly.